# Калькулятор услуг JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, калькулятор

Есть калькулятор услуг, не могу допереть никак, как сделать чтобы он умножал каждое выбранное значение на 30, а не просто приплюсовал?

```js
function calc() {
var post = document.getElementById("post");
var kind1 = document.getElementById("kind1");
var kind2 = document.getElementById("kind2");
var time1 = document.getElementById("time1");
var time2 = document.getElementById("time2");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var price = 0;
price += parseInt(post.options[post.selectedIndex].value);
price += (kind1.checked == true) ? parseInt(kind1.value) : 0;
price += (kind2.checked == true) ? parseInt(kind2.value) : 0;
price += (time1.checked == true) ? parseInt(time1.value) : 0;
price += (time2.checked == true) ? parseInt(time2.value) : 0;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price   
}
```

```html
   <div class="block-calc">
     <p>Тип охраны</p>
      <input class="radio" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="100" id="kind1" name="radio" required />
       <label for="kind1">Вооруженная</label>
      <input class="radio" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="65" id="kind2" name="radio" required />
       <label for="kind2">Невооруженная</label>
     <p>Количество постов</p>
           <select onchange="calc()" id="post">
      <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="780">1 пост</option>
      <option value="1560">2 поста</option>
      <option value="2340">3 поста</option>
      <option value="3120">4 поста</option>
      <option value="3900">5 постов</option>
     </select>
     <p>Количество часов в сутки</p>
      <input class="radio2" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="30" id="time1" name="radio2" required />
       <label for="time1">12 часов</label>
      <input class="radio2" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="60" id="time2" name="radio2" required />
       <label for="time2">24 часа</label>
    <div class="cost">Стоимость: <span id="result">0</span> рублей в месяц</div>
    <div class="za"><a href="#">Заказать</a></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Просто умножьте результат на 30 и делов то

Comment: Замените += ---> *=

Comment: @while1pass пробовал уже, тогда оно вообще перестает считать, 0 в результате стоит

Comment: @Darth помог совет Ваш, сразу как-то не додумался, в выводе результата на 30 умножил, спасибо)